# Get list of files in directory with exclude option

Tags: c#, file-system

This method returns the list of files (absolute path) in a folder (or tree). It allows filtering by extensions or filenames.

The method receives the following parameters:

- `string path`: folder path to scan for files.
- `string[] exclude`: can contain filenames such as `"read.me"` or extensions such as `"*.jpg"`.
- `SearchOption searchOption`: `TopDirectoryOnly` to scan only the specified folder or `AllDirectories` to scan tree folder under the specified path.

The method return files that doesn't appear in `exclude` array and a) hasn't extension, or b) extension doesn't appear in `exclude` array.

---

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string[] exclude, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", searchOption);
        var resultFiles = new List<string>();

        if (exclude.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var filename in files)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

                if (Array.IndexOf(exclude, Path.GetFileName(filename)) >= 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension) || Array.IndexOf(exclude, "*" + extension) < 0)
                {
                    resultFiles.Add(filename);
                }
            }
        }

        return resultFiles;
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend moving `EnumerateFiles` inside the true block of `(exclude.Length > 0)`.  There's no reason to fetch file names otherwise.  Also your check could be `((exclude != null) && (exclude.Length > 0))`.

Comment: @RickDavin why not flesh it up just a little, and then post that as an answer?

Comment: @RickDavin if `exclude` has no elements, the result should be the same as `EnumerateFiles`, so I can't move it inside the true block. I'll add the check against `null`.

Comment: @segarci Your code has written does not reflect what you said.  If `exclude` has no elements, then `resultFiles`, which was initialized a `new List<string>`, is simply returned without referencing anything from `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: @RickDavin You're right man! That's a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're already returning an `IEnumerable<T>` so you might as well turn it into an iterator block. Discard the local `resultFiles` and simply use `yield return filename`.

[MSDN on `yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

---

I don't like that both filenames and extensions are in the same array. If you have 1 extension and 5000 files that have to be excluded, it will iterate over 5000 files (if you have bad luck) for no reason.

---

I would consider using the [`.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) extension method: it's just more expressive than `Array.IndexOf` and should be no difference in performance.

---

I prefer `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` since that also takes care of.. well.. whitespace. You never know if the pesky QA departement tries something like that.

---

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", searchOption);

if (exclude.Length > 0)
{
}

return resultFiles;
```

If there is nothing to exclude, you won't include anything either.

---

A new implementation might look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, IEnumerable<string> excludedFiles, IEnumerable<string> excludedExtensions, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", searchOption);

    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        if(excludedFiles.Contains(file))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(excludedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
        {
            continue;
        }

        yield return file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A few things I noticed:

- If the exclude array is empty you return an empty list instead of every file.
- reversing your logic would allow you to check everything in one statement.
- Since you're returning an `IEnumerable<string>` already, using the yield operator would make sense here.
- Accepting an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of an string[] for the exclude parameter, gives the user more options.  Also this allows you to leverage the LINQ extensions better.

Your code could look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, IEnumerable<string> exclude, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles("*.*", searchOption);
    foreach (var filename in files)
    {

        if (!exclude.Any(x => x == filename.Name || (x.StartsWith("*") && x.Contains(filename.Extension))))
        {
            yield return filename.Name;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @RobH What exactly is meant by "expressive" here? I generally try to avoid using the ! operator in the way that you say is more expressive, because I've seen issues with people not noticing it is there at first, and failing to understand that the condition is being checked against false.

Comment: @Zack -`FirstOrDefault` implies that you want the first element in the sequence which is satisfied by your predicate. If none match, you get the default value. `Any` implies that you want to know if anything matches. That's the part that's more expressive. I haven't worked with anyone who has missed the not operator at the beginning of an expression... Could invert it and use `continue` if that's a problem though.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is that your code does not do lazy enumeration, which means it will load every filenames in your whole drive into memory if you use this method on root directory. To avoid that, the method should either return filtered `IEnumerable<string>` from LINQ method or using `yield return`. Using LINQ is more convenient:

```
private static bool IsExcluded(string fileName, string[] exclude) {
    // if not excluded by filename
    if (exclude.Contains(Path.GetFileName(fileName))) return true;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    return extension == null || exclude.Contains("*" + extension);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, 
    string[] exclude = null, 
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    // I prefer using var keyword for any IEnumerable
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", searchOption);
    if (exclude != null && exclude.Length > 0) {
        files = files.Where(f => !IsExcluded(f, exclude));
    }
    return files;
}
```

I separate exclusion checking into a new method because it is easier to verify that the filter work correctly rather than doing it inline.

Answer (score -2):

Everything that you have written there can be done with a call to: [`Directory.GetFiles(string, string, SearchOption)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is more of a comment than a review of OP's code. Maybe OP didn't know about `Directory.GetFiles`, or maybe OP is purposely reimplementing it - in any case there's nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel if it's for the heck of it.

Comment: It's not exactly reinventing the wheel.  The big difference here is the exclude, which is something that neither GetFiles() nor EnumerateFiles() currently has.  Note the OP uses EnumerateFiles() which is preferred in many ways.

Comment: @Hosch250 I put the link in. This answer didn't enter the VLQ queue because it had a link ;)

Comment: @d347hm4n see [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87034/23788) for an example of a great answer that suggests replacing OP's code with a BCL call.

Comment: GetFiles look at the old and new naming convention for files. Searching for *.txt will also return *.txt123 files. Looping and looking at the extension is still needed.